# Replacing the value of a function with the value of the limit - is this a standard construction?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, notation, terminology

Consider a partial function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Note that, although the *source* of $f$ is $X$, the actual *domain* of $f$ is a (not necessarily proper) subset thereof.

Given this data, we can define a new partial function $f^\lambda : X \rightarrow Y$ by asserting

$$f^\lambda(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$$

and taking the domain of $f^\lambda$ to be the set of all $a \in X$ such that the above limit makes sense. This may include elements $a \in X$ that aren't in the domain of $f$.

Notice that $f^\lambda$ may have a larger or a smaller domain than $f$. Indeed, their domains may be incomparable. Furthermore, it is surprising to note that $f^\lambda$ needn't always be continuous - see Jonas Meyer's answer.

Anyway, my question: is $f^\lambda$ a standard construction? If so, what's the usual terminology/notation?

Comment: How are you defining $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$? Topological spaces needn’t be first countable, so sequences needn’t suffice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I don't know - you can assume the topological spaces are metric spaces if you wish. I just wanted to know whether this was a standard construction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_topological_spaces)'s a rigorous definition.

Comment: You might want to look at [this page](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semicontinuous_function) on semicontinuous functions. I suspect there is a lot of overlap here with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just a remark on the most recent edit: "This may include $a$ that aren't in the domain of $f$."  This means that the definition of $f^\lambda$ will in general depend on which topological space you are considering the domain of $f$ to be a subspace of, so there is another ingredient besides a function between topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows that $f^\lambda$ need not be continuous in general, but in my example the domain of $f$ is not Hausdorff.

---

Let $f:\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$.  Suppose that the domain, $\{0,1\}$ is given the indiscrete topology, in which only $\emptyset$ and $\{0,1\}$ are open, while $\mathbb R$ has its standard topology.

In this case, neither $f$ nor $f^\lambda$ is continuous.  Observe that $f^\lambda(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$, and $f^\lambda(1)=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x)=0$.

Comment: I believe $f^\lambda$ is simply the empty function in this example, rather than what you say it is. Aren't limits defined in terms of punctured neighbourhoods?

Comment: @user18921: To your question, yes they are, and that is what is done here.  Each point in the domain has exactly one neighborhood, namely $\{0,1\}$, so its punctured neighborhood is the singleton containing the other point.

Comment: Oh I see. I added "Hausdorff" as a condition on the topological spaces to ensure uniqueness of limits. Does that alter your conclusion?

Comment: @user18921: I don't know what you mean about altering conclusions.  It makes my answer no longer fit your question.

Comment: Okay your answer is valid given the edit I just made. I needed to require the target of $f$ to be Hausdorff to ensure that limits are well-defined and unique, but I dropped the condition that the source needs to be Hausdorff.

Comment: @user18921: OK, thanks for clarifying.  I noticed and edited my answer again to make clear what it is intended to answer.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your answer, btw. It could have taken more FOREVER to notice that $f^\lambda$ needn't be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You have a uniqueness problem. Consider the signum function

$$\operatorname{sgn}:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
-1,&\text{if }x<0\\
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
1,&\text{if }x>0\;.
\end{cases}$$

You can construct $f^\lambda(x)\equiv-1$ with domain $(\leftarrow,0]$, but you can also construct $f^\lambda(x)\equiv1$ with domain $[0,\to)$. Each of these satisfies your definition, but they can’t be combined: there is no unique maximum function of the desired type.

Comment: I suppose it is not entirely clear, but I had interpreted the definition to mean that $f^\lambda(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ at each point in the domain of $f$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.  If that is the case, then $f^\lambda$ is uniquely determined, and in particular $\mathrm{sgn}^{\lambda}$ has domain $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @user18921: Yes, I am. What you called $\text{sgn}^\lambda$ and my two $f^\lambda$s all satisfy your definition, and **none** of them is maximal.

Comment: @user18921: Ah; if you insist that the limit at $a$ exist for the original function, then indeed this example does not pose a problem.